# How two phases locking ensures serializable?

Tags: locking, isolation-level, serialization

I have read many [sources](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serializability#Other_enforcing_techniques), and they say one of the ways to implement serializable in the database is to use two-phase locking. But I don't really understand how two-phase locking could ensure serializable in this [example](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SSI#Black_and_White) from Jim Gray.

An example is we have two rows in the database, one has the value of **white** and the other one has the value of **black**.
I have two transactions:

- TX1 will update the value of **white** to **black**
- TX2 will update the value of **black** to **white**

If TX1 and TX2 are executed at the same time, then TX1 acquires the lock on the row with the value of **white**, and TX2 acquires the lock on the row with the value of **black**.
So there are no locking conflicts, and eventually, the values are swapped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two phase locking (2PL) alone is insufficient to ensure serializability. Since it allows write locks to be released before the end of our transaction, the system must also track other transactions whose write set overlaps our transaction's write set. Those other transaction's outcomes are dependent on whether our transaction commits or rolls back.

Strong strict two phase locking (SS2PL) holds all read and all write locks until the end of our transaction. Other transactions are unable to acquire locks on objects we already have locks on. Therefore there is no need to track overlapping write sets as such a thing is now impossible.

Serializable isolation level does not allow phantom rows. So the types of lock taken by our transaction is also important. One way is to use key-range locks rather than single-key locks.

Here are some [lecture slides](https://15445.courses.cs.cmu.edu/fall2018/slides/17-twophaselocking.pdf) which cover the topic. 2PL starts around slide 18 though 1-17 are good background. They include many transaction schedules which illustrate, step-by-step, the considerations.

In some DBMS SS2PL does not prevent that anomoly. The reasons why, that I can think of, include definitions, implementation and predicates.

The academic definition of serializable is that it must appear as though one transaction ran to completion before the other started. The SQL standard, however, defines it as "no phantom rows." These are not equivalent. The gap between is where this anomoly creeps in.

High throughput is a good thing to have. So DBMS designers tend to lock the minimum possible. In this case it would be the one "white" row (or "black" row for the other transaction). This allows the anomoly. If the lock had been on the table instead of a row, perhaps because of lock escalation, there would be no anomoly. Doing this for every query, though, would tank performance.

The UPDATE as written states that only white rows should turn black. It has nothing to say about those rows which start as black. If it was tho programmer's intention that every row should have the same colour once the query commits that could be made explicit by omitting the WHERE. I believe existing SS2PL locking implementations would then give desired serializable outcome. (Not saying the programer is at fault here, just showing another gap.)

I suppose it would be possible for a system to track each transaction's write predicates and rollback any that overlaps a previously committed transaction. By the time you've implemented that you're most of the way to a MVCC approach, so just go with that.

Comment: Hi @michael-green, thank you very much for your well-formed answer.

Comment: by the way, in Postgres, I see them use [SSI](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SSI#Black_and_White) to solve the issue which is quite hard to understand :D